# Extracting info from plain text using regexps or other, more efficient method

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I need to extract data from plain text returned from stripping HTML tags from a webpage. The tags were stripped out because the page consists of tabular data, but with tables nested into tables, nested into tables, and so on (really ugly HTML code). After cleaning the code (with HTML Tidy) and stripping out the tags, the site returns info like this:

```
Visitor ID : &nbsp; 123456789 &nbsp; HostName: 127.0.01 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; IP :&nbsp; 127.0.0.1 &nbsp;First Visit -> Entry Page :&nbsp;&nbsp; First   Visit    Entry    Page    Title    Example    First Visit -> Referrer: http://somepage.com   First Visit :  302 Day(s) &nbsp;&nbsp; Last Visit : &nbsp; 09/23/2011 &nbsp;  ISP: Initech &nbsp; Country: &nbsp;Some country Country: &nbsp;Some &nbsp;country    Browser: Chrome   Screen Res: Unknow 4 Billion colors (32 bit) &nbsp; Javascript: Enabled&nbsp;  Page Views: 1&nbsp;    File Downloaded: 0&nbsp; Daily Visits: 1 Visit Length: 0 minutes 0 seconds Entry Page: Entry page title Exit Page: Exit page title   Referring URL: No
```

(As you can see, a very long and random mess)

And I want to turn it into this:

```
Visitor ID: 123456789
HostName: 127.0.01
IP: 127.0.01
First Visit: 302 Day(s)
First Visit -> Entry Page: First Visit Entry Page Title Example
First Visit -> Referrer: http://somepage.com
Last Visit: 09/23/2011
ISP: Initech
Country: Some country
Country: Some country
Browser: Chrome
Screen Res: Unknow 4 Billion colors (32 bit) 
Javascript: Enabled
Page Views: 1
File Downloaded: 0
Daily Visits: 1
Visit Length: 1 minute(s) 26 second 
Entry Page: Entry page title
Exit Page: Exit page title
Referring URL: No
```

I'm currently using regexps to remove extra whitespace and try to sort the data. So far, it's almost working using this:

```
$patterns       = array("/HostName\s*:/",
                        "/IP\s*:/",
                        "/First\s+Visit\s+->\s+Entry\s+Page\s*:/",
                        "/First\s+Visit\s+->\s+Referrer\s*:/",
                        "/First\s+Visit\s*:/",
                        "/\bLast\s+Visit\s*:/",
                        "/\bISP\s*:/",
                        "/\bCountry\s*:/",
                        "/\bBrowser\s*:/",
                        "/\bScreen\s*Res\s*:/",
                        "/\bJavascript\s*:/",
                        "/\bPage\s+Views\s*:/",
                        "/\bFile\s+Downloaded\s*:/",
                        "/\bDaily\s+Visits\s*:/",
                        "/\bVisit\s+Length\s*:/",
                        "/\bEntry\s+Page\s*:/",
                        "/\bExit\s+Page\s*:/",
                        "/\bReferring\s+URL\s*:/",
                        "/\bFrom\s+Campaign\s*:/"   );

$replacements   = array("\nHostName:",
                        "\nIP:",
                        "\nFirst Visit -> Entry Page:",
                        "\nFirst Visit -> Referrer:",
                        "\nFirst Visit:",
                        "\nLast Visit:",
                        "\nISP:",
                        "\nCountry:",
                        "\nBrowser:",
                        "\nScreen Res:",
                        "\nJavascript:",
                        "\nPage Views:",
                        "\nFile Downloaded:",
                        "\nDaily Visits:",
                        "\nVisit Length:",
                        "\nEntry Page:",
                        "\nExit Page:",
                        "\nReferring URL:",
                        "\nFrom Campaign:"  );
ksort( $patterns );
ksort( $replacements );

$fixed_text      = preg_replace ( $patterns, $replacements, $ugly_mess );
```

However, this isn't really working as expected. Note that some fields are similar, and the regexp fails to work, resulting in something like this:

```
Visitor ID: 123456789 
HostName: 127.0.0.1 
IP: 127.0.0.1 
Last Visit: 302 Day(s) 
First Visit: 10 June 2010 
First Visit -> 
Entry Page: First Visit Entry Page Title Example
First Visit -> Referrer: http://somepage
.com
ISP: Initech 
Country: Some Country 
Country: Some Country 
Browser: Chrome
Screen Res: Unknow 4 Billion colors (32 bit) 
Javascript: Enabled  
Page Views: 1
File Downloaded: 0 
Daily Visits: 1
Visit Length: 1 minute(s) 26 second 
Entry Page: Entry page title
Exit Page: Exit page title
Referring URL: No
```

I might be going about this the wrong way, so that's why I'm asking for suggestions or fixes to the current code. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it with replace pattern, what if you use match. I'm using javascript, but you could easily change it back to PHP.

```js
  var pattern = "^(?:";
  pattern += "(?:Visitor\\s*ID\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:HostName\s*:\\s*([^ ]+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:IP\\s*:\\s*([^ ]+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:First\\s*Visit\\s*->\\s*Entry Page\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=First\\s*Visit\\s*->))";
  pattern += "|(?:First\\s*Visit\\s*->\\s*Referrer\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=First\\s*Visit\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:First\\s*Visit\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*Day\\(s\\)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:Last\\s*Visit\\s*:\\s*(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:ISP\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=Country\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:Country\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=(?:Country|Browser)\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:Browser\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=Screen\\s*Res\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:Screen\\s*Res\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=Javascript\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:Javascript\\s*:\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=Page\\s*Views\\s*:))";
  pattern += "|(?:Page\\s*Views\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:File\\s*Downloaded\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:Daily\\s*Visits\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*)";
  pattern += "|(?:Visit\\s*Length\\s*:\\s*((?:\\d+ (?:hours|minutes|seconds)\\s*)+))";
  pattern += ")+";
  var regex = new RegExp(pattern);

  var content = readData().replace(/&nbsp;/g, "");
  var match = content.match(regex);
  echo("Visitor Id: " + match[1]);
  echo("Hostname: " + match[2]);
  echo("IP: " + match[3]);
  // continue on...
```